# IOS Project Clone management with Git Branches

Tags: git, structure, bitbucket, branch

I need help from solution architect level persons. We are developing a app of stock market and we are providing our solutions to many exchangers, basically a clone with different UI and few logical stuff as well.

What will be a best structure to manage this problem, so we can save our efforts each time we put in case of new clone.

Regarding the GIT Branches, its for the same project with different versions. But we have one project with different clones and Few changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider applying the componentized development. A simple example could be like:

1. Make your common project to be a Framework.
2. A specific project use the Framework and apply a few changes.